# HELP! Alignment in shopping cart with multiple dropdowns

Tags: cart, css, ajax

HELP! I start my PHP/Magento class in a few weeks, but until then, I could use help. Anyone have time to point me in the right direction here?

I have been researching how to align the shopping cart drop downs/input boxes and haven't been able to find a solution. I would like this to be in the CSS so that when any it is any product, of any quantity the alignment will be correct.

I located where I update this particular page by turning on the template path hints, but think I need to go elsewhere if it's going to be CSS driven. I went into the styles.css and swapped center for left, flushed the cache and no change. I then changed back to keep it the way it was.

Am I in the correct area for this page/cart (for all, actually)? http://awesomescreenshot.com/0963c8xi36

Does anyone have time to look at this code and see what you would suggest? I have attached the code and a screen shot. Do you need anything else to help?

Thanks much! Beth

Here is my code  http://jsfiddle.net/BNeely1101/gzc2th56/

Comment: Unfortunately this question may be closed because, though it has to do with Magento, it is more of a CSS-based issue and not strictly dealing with the Magento frontend framework itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since I just got started on stack exchange, I can't add comments, but after looking at your site, the easiest solution is to go into your styles.css file and remove "float: left" from the .product-view label (line 2871). However, this will put the label (water supply, for example) on a separate line as the drop down. (optionally, you can also remove the "width: 90px;" so the label doesn't take up two lines).

If you want the label and the drop-down on the same line, KEEP the float: left and remove the "padding-top: 6px" instead. **add margin-bottom: ## px; to line 3691
 (.product-shop #product-options-wrapper dl dd ) to space them out further**

Comment: http://theh2oguru.com/drinking-water-system/water-cop-5-stage-ro-50-gpd.html  Thanks so much, Krista! I certainly appreciate your help.

Comment: I changed my original answer to better answer your question. not sure if it notifies you :)

Comment: see revised answer again regarding your spacing question.